# Using Bootstrap Datepicker with Select2

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-select2, bootstrap-datepicker

As I'm using the select2 library across my application, I want to use it with a calendar where selecting a date populates the option fields of the select field.

I've tried a number of methods, for example, calling the datepicker when the select2 field is clicked.

```
        $("#createReportDateOptions").select2().on("select2:opening", function () {
        $("#createReportDateOptions").datepicker({
            multidate: true
        });
    })
```

The problem is, I believe, that datepicker requires a text field, whereas select2 requires a select field (or it converts a text field to a select field).

Does anyone have any suggestions as to how I can combine the two plugins? Other ideas I've had include making an invisible overlay or changing the select to input and vice versa when clicked. However, these seem a little complicated for what I feel should be a pretty simple task.

Thanks

Comment: The issue with using `datepicker` and `select2` is that `Datepicker` doesn't have a *"after show"* **callback function** that can run code after show the datepicker. Please see [this DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/Shady_Alset/uwraua65/). _i hope it helps, thanks !_

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's what `show` does: http://bootstrap-datepicker.readthedocs.org/en/latest/events.html#show